# Testing API calls between two local projects running on Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use GuzzleHttp to make a POST request from projectA to projectB. Both of the projects run on the same Homestead instance. Problem is the endpoint doesn't get the request.

The Windows **hosts** file:

```
192.168.10.10 projectA.local
192.168.10.10 projectB.local
```

The **GuzzleHttp call** in projectA:

```
$this->httpClient = new Client(array(
    'base_uri' => 'http://projectB.local/api/'
));

$response = $this->httpClient->post('create-user', array('form_params' => $this->params));

return $response->getStatusCode();
```

**Debug in projectB:**

```
public function createUser(Request $request) {
    Logger::debug('API call received'); // custom logging of the call in the database
}
```

Now, this API call is never logged in the DB. **projectA sends the request, but projectB doesn't receive it.**

**What I confirmed:**

- The `$this->params` is set and correct (these are the POST params)
- The endpoint URI is correct (http://projectB.local/api/create-user)
- The endpoint exists in projectB, is accessible and responds to POST
- The response status code is `200`

What am I missing? Is it not possible to call one Homestead project from another one?

---

**UPDATE - configuration from Homestead**

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       homestead       homestead
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       vagrant.vm      vagrant
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.0.2.3
```

**/etc/nsswitch.conf**

```
> grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
> hosts:          files dns
```

**host check**

```
> host projectB.local
> Host projectB.local not found: 4(NOTIMP)
> Host projectB.local not found: 4(NOTIMP)
```

Comment: can you show your virtual host configurations?

Comment: @VaheGalstyan Sure. Updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I started thinking that it might be something breaking the API call before the endpoint is reached. I have some global middlewares running on every request (e.g. the `VerifyCsrfToken` one).

I made sure my endpoint path is excluded from processing in the middlewares and that was it:

```
if (!$request->is('api/*)) {
    // handle...
}
```

Specifically, in the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware, you can use the provided field:

```
protected $except = [
    'api/*'
];
```

Sounds so obvious now it's almost disgusting.